# Proving that $f(x)=0\ \forall x\in B(0,r)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $y=f(x_1,…,x_n)$ be differentiable on $B(0,r)$.

Assume that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x)=0\  \forall x\in B(0,r)$ and $i\in\{1,…,n\}$.

How to prove that $f(x)=0\ \forall x\in B(0,r)$?

Do I need to use Lagrange's mean value theorem?

Comment: You can at most show that it is constant.

Comment: As stated, your statement is false. $f(x,y)=1$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For each $y\in B(0,r)$, consider the function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$,

$$g(t) = f(ty).$$

Then apply mean value theorem to this $g$ (Chain rule should be used).

Remark: After all these you can only show that $f$ is constant. Might not be zero though.